# First time application is opened?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

The first time my application is downloaded and opened, I want the "Help" window to automatically open.

How would I go upon doing this? Note I only want the it to open automatically the **first** time the application is launched.

Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Xcode 3.2.6

Answer (score 5):

Many ways of doing this, one of them is using `NSUserDefaults` to store a value "`firstRun`" and set that to `YES` when you first run. Obviously if you don't find a value for `firstRun` or it's set to `NO`, its your first run.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html